# Windows Phone, set image source on async callback doesn't work?

Tags: image, asynchronous, windows-phone

I am getting images from Bing to display in my app. I followed Bing's instructions, I successfully retrieve the image's URLs, but for some reason, the emulator won't display them! Here's what I have

```
var bingContainer = new Bing.BingSearchContainer(new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/"));

            var accountKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(accountKey, accountKey);

            var imageQuery = bingContainer.Image("porsche", null, null, null, null, null, "Size:Medium");

            imageQuery.BeginExecute(new AsyncCallback(this.ImageResultLoadedCallback), imageQuery);
```

Then, I get my images and try to set them here:

```
var imageQuery = (DataServiceQuery<Bing.ImageResult>)ar.AsyncState;

        var enumerableImages = imageQuery.EndExecute(ar);
        var imagesList = enumerableImages.ToList();

        List<String> imList = new List<String>();

        while (imList.Count != 3)
        {
            Bing.ImageResult tr = imagesList.First<Bing.ImageResult>();
            if (tr.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
            {
                imList.Add(tr.MediaUrl);
            }
            imagesList.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@imList[0]));
        image2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@imList[1]));
        image3.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@imList[2]));
```

When I debug, the process seems to just stop on those three last lines where I set the source.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after two days of frustration, I found out you cannot access the UI thread from an async callback. VS wasn't giving any errors, yet the images were not showing. An async callback runs alongside the main UI thread, so it can't access or change the elements in the UI. The easy workaround just involves wrapping the lines of code that access the UI like this:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@imList[0]));
            image2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@imList[1]));
            image3.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@imList[2])); 
        });
```

It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure MediaUrl is returning proper urls to images? What if you would use some hardcoded urls to images in the imList list, would the images load properly in image1, image2 and image3? The point i am getting to is that perhaps the quality of the data is incorrect. That is, though your query executes well, MediaURL is not containing a properly formatted URL.

Also, what is the exception you get when the debugger stops?